# <th> element won't activate on :hover

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover, styling

I have a table with multiple heads inside `th` tags where I want to be able to change another element `#box1` to be shown when hovering over the `#heading` element. This works when replacing the `th` tag with `div` or `section` tags. Why wont it work with `th` tags?

```css
#heading {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#box1 {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#heading:hover + #box1 {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table id="main-players-container">

  <tr id="headings">
    <th id="heading">Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="box1">
  <p>box to change css</p>
</div>
```

Comment: First check your HTML syntax. You can’t have a div as a direct child of a tr element.

Comment: That's invalid HTML - no divs as direct children of a `tr` allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at how the browser has rendered your HTML, you'll see that it's recognised that the `div` isn't part of the table structure and will have rendered it outside the table, so the adjacent sibling combinator (`+`) won't work as the div is no longer a sibling of the `th` element

---

**Edited to add following comments below**

This can be achieved by wrapping the whole section in a div and using the :has pseudo class as below. Note that :has() isn't fully supported yet (see [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas) for details)

```css
#heading {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#box1 {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container:has(#heading:hover) #box1 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <table id="main-players-container">
    <tr id="headings">
      <th id="heading">Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div id="box1">
    <p>box to change css</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what combinator would i use instead?

Comment: What is the layout supposed to be? Do you want the red div block above the words 'Name' and 'Price' because with your code it's rendering as <div id='box1'></div><table>...</table> in the browser.

Comment: i will have it displayed after the closing `table` tag

Comment: I've added an example but beware :has() isn't fully implemented on browsers yet.